# Ionic AlertController as Service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have place the Ionic 2 prompt in a provider(service) like so..

```
showPromptOk(title, message, callback) {    

       let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: title || 'Alert!',
          message: message,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: data => {
                if(callback) callback(data);
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        prompt.present();
      }
```

I call it like this..

```
updateAccount() {
    let self = this;
    this.sk_account.update(this.account)
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.sk_utils.showPromptOk('Success!', 'Your account has been updated!',  (res) => {

            self.edit_account = false;
            self.edit_school = false;

          });
        }
      )
  }
```

The problem, is that "this" or "self" in this case is no longer valid, it becomes the context of the provider(service). How can I set up the handler to pass the "scope" back top the original caller so that when I set the values they are actually setting them in the original component scope, not the provider scope?

UPDATE 1:

After adding callback(data) I am noticing the view model is no longer getting updated. You can see in the console the values are now set to false, but the {{edit_account}} interpolation on the view is not getting updated. Notice the variable is still "true" on the view. Any ideas?

[image: still true]

Notice in the console, the data is not false but the view is not updated.
[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to pass data here: `handler: data => {
                if(callback) callback(data);
              }`

Comment: is this a typo?

Comment: Is what a typo?

Comment: my first comment.. you are not passing data to callback in your `showPromptOk`..is that a typo in your question or is that a mistake in the code?

Comment: Yes but how is that going to automatically resolve my issue? Don't I need to do something with that data?

Comment: no.. you are using arrow functions for callbacks so the scope is of the class where the function is defined..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Ok will try adding "data"

Comment: Please see my update to the question.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you create a plunker to illustrate this problem so we can all help.

Comment: Apparently we have to use angular "detectChanges" on the callback, just like angular JS uses scope apply() this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with Subject: the `showPromptOk` take the subject and the handler calls the 'next method'
In Account component, add a subject and its subscription, the updating logic must be in the subscription

Ps: the Subject must be static

```
static AccountMustBeUpdated: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

ionViewDidLoad(){
AccoutsPage.AccountMustBeUpdated.subscribe(
() => { /* Your update logic here*/} );
```

Dont forget to unsubscribe from the subject to avoid troubles